# How do I run a PHP script through SSH using MAMP?

Tags: mac, php, mamp

I have a PHP socket script that I run from SSH on a remote dedicated server, but I want to try doing that using MAMP with SSH.

I have MAMP configured and am running a remote web server on port 80.  I also have remote login enabled in sharing in system preferences and am able to SSH into localhost.

Once I SSH into localhost, I can't do much; the current directory seems empty.  How can I get to my PHP file from there and open it so the socket runs?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "type dirs?"

Comment: i clarified my post

Comment: Great!  I wonder if you're SSH'ing into a "chroot'ed" environment that provides you with access only to an empty path.  Do you have root access to the system, or are you logging in as a regular user?  I'm suspecting file system permissions.

Comment: i'm logging in as a myself using my username. ideally i'd want to access the ssh of mamp and not my computer 'terminal' if that makes sense.